# Raspberry pi how to expose a port when a docker running a web server

Tags: pi-2, port-forwarding, docker

I have the following configuration in Raspberry Pi for iptables

```
            pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables --list
            Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
            target     prot opt source               destination
            ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
            REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
            ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
            ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
            ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
            ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt
            ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8181
            ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8182
            ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
            ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
            LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
            DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

            Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
            target     prot opt source               destination
            DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
            DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
            ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
            DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
            ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
            ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
            DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

            Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
            target     prot opt source               destination
            ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

            Chain DOCKER (1 references)
            target     prot opt source               destination
            ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:8181

            Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
            target     prot opt source               destination
            RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

            Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
            target     prot opt source               destination
            RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

and I have exposed port 8181 in Docker file. This device has a static IP of 192.168.100.20 and I can ping in to it from my host machine.

This is the docker file configuration

```
            FROM myapp

            COPY . /app
            RUN pip install -e /app
            WORKDIR /app/node

            EXPOSE 8181

            ENTRYPOINT [ "myapp", "run" ]
```

I am running as  `docker run -p 8181:8181 <image_id>`

But when I tried to access it by its IP, it says address not found and when I do a port scan, I'm getting the following result

```
            Discovered closed port 8181/tcp on 192.168.100.20
            8181/tcp  closed   intermapper          conn-refused
```

What prevents accessing it from outside the Raspberry Pi device ?

Comment: Just to make sure it isn't something with docker interface configuration, explicitly list your external interface as in `-p 192.168.100.20:8181:8181` or, alternatively, `-p 0.0.0.0:8181:8181`

Comment: @crasic I tried it and didnt work

Comment: On the host machine, can you connect directly to the container at `172.17.0.2:8181`

Comment: @crasic seems I cannot connect did a curl for 172.17.0.1:8181

Comment: Are you sure that is the container IP? `docker inspect <container_id>`. In any case, if that is the container IP then the firewall/networking is not the problem, but your image does not have anything bound to that port, or, you have configured the image to block that port. Even though it is exposed in `Dockerfile`, there is "no one home" so to speak.

Comment: It has an IP address 172.17.0.2 and it uses the bridge network

Answer (score 1):

What does 'myapp' do ?

Are you sure it does listen on port 8181 of the container's external interface (or on all interfaces) ?

Are you sure 'myapp' starts correctly ?

Does

```
$ docker logs <container id>
```

give you any error or debug message ?

If your images contains netstat, the output of

```
$ docker exec <container id> netstat -lnp
```

would show if anything in the container listens on the public port 8181.

To debug such situations I'd recommend to start your image in interactive mode:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -p 8181:8181 <image_id> /bin/bash
```

and then start your app manually inside the container with

```
$ myapp run
```

ideally adding some flags to add more verbosity to your app if your app supports it.

It doesn't seem to be a raspberry issue but a configuration of your image.